# unclear on ES6 destructuring function parameter defaults

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

So in the MDN documentation for destructuring function defaults it gives the following example.

```
function drawES2015Chart({size = 'big', cords = {x: 0, y: 0}, radius = 
25} = {}) {
  console.log(size, cords, radius);
  // do some chart drawing
}

drawES2015Chart({
  cords: {x: 18, y: 30},
  radius: 30
});
```

However I can run this example with the first line as `function drawES2015Chart({size = 'big', cords = {x: 0, y: 0}, radius = 
25})`

so leaving out the `={}` part. I'm not sure why this works and what the advantages would be to using the longer form if the shorter form is in fact equally correct.

Comment: What happens when you pass in `nil`/`undefined`/nothing in your version? (E.g., w/o the `= {}` default.)

Comment: @DaveNewton you still get an exception when passing `null`, because it does not trigger the default value substitution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refactoring the function as you suggest:

```
function drawES2015Chart({size = 'big', cords = {x: 0, y: 0}, radius = 25}) {
    console.log(size, cords, radius);
}
```

Would cause an error when attempting to call it with no arguments:

```
drawES2015Chart(); // throws TypeError
```

However, you may call it as:

```
drawES2015Chart({});
```

So, what the `= {}` is doing at the end is making you able to invoke

```
drawES2015Chart();
```

Which will be defaulted to

```
drawES2015Chart({});
```

Which will be defaulted to

```
drawES2015Chart({size = 'big', cords = {x: 0, y: 0}, radius = 25});
```

Answer (score 4):

The final `= {}` defaulting the entire argument object to make sure you don't try to destructure `undefined` if someone called your function without any arguments at all (`drawES2015Chart({})` vs `drawES2015Chart()`)

If you didn't have this guard:

```
function foo({x = 10}) {
  return x;
}

foo(); // TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
foo({}); // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try delete *= {}* and execute drawES2015Chart();

It prevents *undefined* from being destructured.